# Can you buy bus tickets on the spot in Split and Plitvice, Croatia?

Tags: tickets, buses, croatia

I'm trying to get from Split to Plitvice after landing at 10 am, then from Plitvice to Zagreb the following evening, and it's been really frustrating. I haven't even been able to figure out who runs the buses - a company or the state.

I've seen sites that would have me buy a ticket, but they say I have to print it out, and as I'm presently Airbnb hopping I don't think I'll be able to do that.

This is for next week and I'm worried I'm going to get stranded over there.

Will I be able to buy tickets at stations?

Is it likely to be sold out?

Comment: Buses seem to be run by various companies, but schedules listed centrally by the bus stations. Whether these are still state concerns or privatized isn't entirely clear to me. In general, tickets on the spot are the norm. These comments are based on experiences that largely predate Croatia's accession to the EU, however, so things could well be different now.

Comment: Retrospective informational comment: I bought a ticket online for leaving Plitvice; the buses came right to where they said they would within 0-15 minutes of *when* they said they would. The buses were very comfortable and nice. Well worth it. I bought the ticket for leaving Split on the spot, worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

There are many private bus companies on both the routes from Split to Plitivice and from Plitvice to Zagreb. Buses in Croatia normally don't sell out, though they may in particularly busy travel periods, I think you should be fine in October.

[BalkanViaTor](https://www.balkanviator.com/en/bus-timetables/) has done a pretty good job at collecting the schedules in one place. You can book tickets in advance for a few bus companies on [GetByBus](https://getbybus.com).

Here's some info on going from [Split Airport to the station](https://getbybus.com/en/blog/airport-bus-split/). Buying at the station in Split should be fine, in Plitivice you have to wait at unsuspecting bus stops near the park entrances and pay the attendant on the bus or driver - you should be able to find a bus no problem but you may need a little patience. You may be best off booking ahead with [Autotrans](https://www.autotrans.hr/en-us/plitvice-lakes-2) bus company since they have several departures and market heavily to tourists, I'd think their buses might be easier to find in Plitivice, and if you miss one there's likely to be a later departure.

Answer (score 3):

There are many *private* companies running the buses. The Split buss station is near the south and of the port. There are several counters there and you can ask which ones go to Plitvice. Many but not all do. Hint: Many Plitvice buses have a photo of waterfalls printed on their side.

There should be no trouble at all buying bus tickets in Split but make sure to buy you return ticket too. Plitvice has no real bus stations and a bus stop is loosely defined as a segment of the highway which goes through the area. On one of the stops near our hotel in Plitvice, there was someone waiting for passengers but she was not of much help and did not want to use her phone to call for us when there were no buses or taxis arriving.